# Having trouble with background image to show up for a section of the front page

Tags: html, css, image, background, portfolio

I'm trying to get an image to appear over text and it doesn't show up. It's my first time asking a question here too so sorry if it's kind of... vague?

I have a front page and I only want the top section of it to have a fixed BG picture, I will add text (profile intro) over it. I've tried the following ways but it shows up as a block to move the text underneath, disappears or just goes over the text.

1. I've tried making a class of the BG image to put into html div with the profile-intro class within that. It didn't work.
2. I tried using z-index in CSS which led to nothing.
3. I tried to img src the BG image into the bgimage class, and it comes up with with this in the CSS file. (I don't know how to link it.)

```css
  /*CSS Code for Cover Photo*/

.home-bg-cover-photo {
  background-image: image(Dark_Eventide_Flipped_2500.jpg);
  margin: -10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: 100%, auto;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML Code for where photo appears -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="home-bg-cover-photo">
    <h1> Hi, I'm sadnoodle. </h1>
    <!--This is the text that appears on top of BG photo -->
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

NEW CODE (2nd edit)

/*CSS Code for Cover Photo*/

```
.home-bg-cover-photo {
  background-image: url("images/homepage/Dark_Eventide_Flipped_2500.jpg");
  margin: -10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: 100%, auto;
}


<!--HTML Code for where photo appears -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="home-bg-cover-photo">
    <h1> Hi, I'm sadnoodle. </h1>
    <!--This is the text that appears on top of BG photo -->
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the CSS should have url(), not image()

Comment: There is no closing bracket in CSS. There is no closing </div> tag in HTML. And what @mplungjan wrote in the comment above.

Comment: This probably sounds kind of dumb, but I did notice there was a url option.When I typed 'background-image' it gives me option for url() or img().

The image I'm referencing is not a url site, but I have it in my assets folder. So this whole project is my portfolio (SadNoodle_Portfolio), which I have two folders and the picture is in 'Images', the image name is 'bg.jpg'. So I'm not sure how to reference it.

Comment: @54ka Thanks, I just fixed the errors (for this question). I manually retyped the code in just to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a url("") in your code.

```
background-image: url("../assets/images/image-name.jpg").
```

Comment: It didn't work. This is what I have in the CSS Class atm:

.home-bg{
     background-image: url('/Images/HomePage/Dark_Eventide_Flipped_2500.jpg');
}

HTML
<div class ="home-bg">
</div>